# Compiling problems using mock of CMocka

Tags: c, powershell, unit-testing, cmocka

I'm trying to compile the chef example from the CMocka project examples - [link](https://gitlab.com/cmocka/cmocka/-/tree/master/example/mock/chef_wrap).

When I'm compiling it without the mocking flags there are no compilation problems. When I'm trying to compile it using the defined flags I get compiling error:

```
gcc -g -Wl,--wrap=chef_cook cmocka.c waiter_test_wrap.c chef.c
```

I receive the following error line:

```
    At line:1 char:11
+ gcc -g -Wl,--wrap=chef_cook cmocka.c waiter_test_wrap.c chef.c
+           ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

I've seen several examples and I don't find any syntax problems. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't look like a compiler error, but rather a PowerShell error.

Comment: You are right! Using simple CMD compile it. Why this is happening on PowerShell?

Comment: While I recognize the error as a PowerShell error, I don't really know anything else about PowerShell. Perhaps it uses comma to mean something different? Perhaps you need to quote the argument like `"-Wl,--wrap=chef_cook"`?

Comment: Yes, it works as well. I will read more about it to understand the difference. Thank you.